# Переименовать .pdf файлы в папке

Tags: python, ос

Я использую следующий код, для того, чтобы переименовать pdf файлы в папке.

```
import os

ext = "pdf"
i = 117582
dir = 'путь'
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if file.endswith(ext):
        os.rename(f'{dir}/{file}', f'{dir}/ФО {+i}.{ext}')
        i = i - 1
```

Операционная система macOS. Моя цель - в папке содержится nn-ое кол-во файлов. Первый файл в данном примере я хочу назвать ФО 117582. Я хочу переименовать и все последующие файлы уменьшая числовую составляющую первого файла на 1. Но данный код почему-то переименовывает файлы в разнобой, а не по порядку, как они находятся в папке. Помогите с решением проблемы, спасибо.

Comment: У файлов в папке нет никакого порядка.

Comment: А как у вас называются исходные файлы? Можно их отсортировать. Либо вычислять новое имя из старого. Так то порядок перечисления файлов в каталоге - штука неопределённая.

Comment: Исходные файлы просто называются по порядку от 1 до 50, если файлов в папке 50. В папке файл с именем 1 - как раз ФО 117582. Хочу чтобы файл с именем 2 назывался ФО 117581 и так далее.

Comment: Если вам нужен упорядоченный определённым образом список файлов, значит напишите и запустите нужную вам функцию сортировки списка, например https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710

Comment: Не могу понять, как использовать эту функция для последующего переименования файлов. С ее помощью я могу получить список с именами файлов от 1 до 50 (например) и уже по нему использовать код из вопроса?

Comment: sorted для os.listdir(dir) тоже не помог